# How to copy local filesystem into Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a local project directory structure like:

```
config
    test
        docker-compose.yaml
        DockerFile
        pip-requirements.txt
src
    app
        app.py
```

I'm trying to use Docker to spin up a container to run app.py. Simple in concept, but this has proven extraordinarily difficult. I'm keeping my Docker files in a separate sub-folder because I plan on having a large number of different environments, and I don't want to clutter my top-level folder with dozens of files like `Dockerfile.1`, `Dockerfile.2`, etc.

My docker-compose.yaml looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    worker:
        image: myname:mytag
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        volumes:
            -  ./src/app:/usr/local/myproject/src/app
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:2.7

# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /usr/local/myproject/src/app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container.
COPY src/app /usr/local/myproject/src/app
COPY pip-requirements.txt pip-requirements.txt

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r pip-requirements.txt

# Define environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

CMD ["./app.py"]
```

If I run from the top-level directory of my project:

```
docker-compose -f config/test/docker-compose.yaml up
```

it succeeds in building the image, but fails when attempting to run the image with the error:

```
ERROR: for worker  Cannot start service worker: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"./app.py\": stat ./app.py: no such file or directory": unknown
```

If I inspect the image's filesystem with:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash myname:mytag
```

it correctly dumps me into `/usr/local/myproject/src/app`. However, this directory is empty, explaining the runtime error. Why is this empty? Shouldn't the `COPY` statement and `volumes` have populated the image with my application code?

Answer (score 1):

For one, you're clobbering the data set by including the content during the build stage and then using docker-compose to overlay a directory on top of it. Let's first discuss the differences between the Dockerfile (Image) and the Docker-compose (Runtime)

Normally, you would use the `COPY` directive in the dockerfile to copy a component of your local directory into the image so that it is *immutable*. In most application deployments, this means we bundle our entire application into the directory and prepare it to run. This means that it is not dynamic (Meaning changes you make to the code after that are not visible in the container) but is a gain in terms of security.

Docker-compose is a *runtime* specification meaning, "Once I have an image, I want to programmatically define how it runs". By defining a volume here, you're saying "I want the local directory (From the perspective of the compose file) `/src/app` to be overlaid onto `/usr/local/myproject/src/app`

Thus anything you built into the image doesn't really matter. You're adding another layer on top of the image which will take precedance over what was built into the image.

It may also be something to do with you specifying the Workdir already and then specifying a ./ reference in the CMD. Would be worth trying it as just `CMD ["app.py"]`

What happens if you

1. Build the image: `docker build -t "test" .`
2. Run the image manually : `"docker run --rm -it test`

Comment: Running it manually, I get the same error. Removing "./" makes no difference because the file doesn't exist anywhere. The COPY/volume statements are effectively being ignored, and no application code is being copied into the container.